# Reg uploading additional files in docker hub

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is there any possibilities in keeping additional files in the docker hub account along with docker images.

There is description page, but I want to maintain additional files for each image I planning to upload. Currently bundling the files in the image and retrieving it through creating container from it. It would be great if that option available.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Docker Hub will keep the **image**. Anything else associated with the image needs to be kept in the source repository linked to the image in the registry.